# How to specify a fixed shipping rate for each product separatly?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, table-rates

I'm using magento C.E 1.7.0.2. I have given table rate shipping for the countries except **US** with the condition **price vs destination per order**.

Now I want to give some fixed shipping rates for some special products when they are shipped internationally (other than US). I mean, I want exempt these products from the table rate and apply special shipping price.

How can I achieve this? I tried **shopping cart price rule**. But it provides only a discount for the total amount at the order review not in the shipping price.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of handling this is to use a module that allows per item flat rate shipping. Webshopapps has a couple items in their module lineup that will allow you to accomplish this. And will allow per country, state or zipcode range freight calculation.

Hacking the weight field as mentioned in another answer on stackoverflow is a short-sighted fix that then destroys future proper use if this field and the freight calculations that are based off it.

Painting yourself into a corner, Magento allows it, you won't like the Never-Release Flypaper you just created for yourself. BTDT, the tee shirt had a rude, self-deprecating message...

Answer (score 0):

Following thread may help you to set shipping cost on product level

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599818/how-to-set-shipping-cost-per-product